# eclipse does not display classes folder in target

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, ant

After I finish building from Ant, All my class files are imported into the classes folder inside target folder. I checked that the classes folder does indeed exist in my file system. 
However, for some reason the eclipse does not recognize this folder. Every time I run a JUnit test, it always show this:

```
Class not found AbsenceReportControllerTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AbsenceReportControllerTest
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:693)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:429)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

This folder also does not display in eclipse's Package Explorer

I tried to project > clean and rebuild, close and restart the eclipse and typing F5, but none of those approaches works.

Could you please help me figure out how to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, it is because I chose that folder to be my output folder in eclipse project >  properties. I simply removed it from the .classpath file so that I can see it again.For eclipse kepler . Uncheck box for "allow output folder for source folder" in java build path.